# manual calculation of partial derivation in glsl (compare with dFdx)

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I suppose dFdx(variable) could be implemented by manual as the following example:

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

float circle (const vec2 st, float r) {
    return sin(300.0 * length(st));
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    st.x *= u_resolution.x / u_resolution.y;
    float dist = circle(st, 0.5);
    float df;
    df = dFdx(dist) * 100.0;
    df = (circle(st + vec2(1.0 / u_resolution.x, 0.0), 0.5) - dist) * 100.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(df), 1.0);
}
```

but the result makes different, the manual way seems to be smooth, could someone explains more about it?

[image] (manual)

[image] (dFdx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is not completly correct.

Yes [`dFdx`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml) calculates the difference (partial derivative) of an expression of 2 neighbour fragments.

But no, it is not always the difference of the current fragment and the **next** fragment in the row.

For the difference can be considered, that a 2x2 square of fragments is evaluated at once. In this square the difference of the "left" and "right" fragments (`dFdx`) is calculated. The result is the result of `dFdx` for the "left" fragment and the invertieren result for the "right" fragments:

For a detailed specification see

- [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 8.14.1. Derivative Functions; page 189](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)
- [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification - 8.14.1. Derivative Functions; page 153](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf)
- [OES_standard_derivatives](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_standard_derivatives.txt)

To emulate this, you have to calculate the result of the successor and predecessor:

```
float dist   = circle(st, 0.5);
float dist_n = circle(st + offs_x, 0.5);
float dist_p = circle(st - offs_x, 0.5);
```

For the even fragments in the row you have to calculate the difference of the expression of the next fragment and current fragment:

```
df = (dist_n - dist) * 100.0;
```

For the odd fragments in the row you have to calculate the difference of the expression of the current fragment and the previous fragment:

```
df = (dist - dist_p) * 100.0;
```

See the WebGL example, which compares the result of `dFdx` at the left side and the emulated result at the right side:

```js
(function loadscene() {

var gl, canvas, prog, bufObj = {};

function render(deltaMS) {

  gl.viewport( 0, 0, vp_size[0], vp_size[1] );
  gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
  gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
  ShProg.Use( progDraw );
  ShProg.SetF2( progDraw, "u_resolution", vp_size );
  VertexBuffer.Draw( bufRect );

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}  

function initScene() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
  //gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl2" );
  if (!gl)
      return null;
  var standard_derivatives = gl.getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives");  // dFdx, dFdy
  if (!standard_derivatives)
      alert('no standard derivatives support (no dFdx, dFdy)');
    
  progDraw = ShProg.Create( 
    [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
      { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
    ] );
  progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.progObj, "inPos" );
  if ( progDraw.progObj == 0 )
      return;

  bufRect = VertexBuffer.Create(
  [ { data :  [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ], attrSize : 2, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos } ],
    [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ] );

  window.onresize = resize;
  resize();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
  //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
  vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
  vp_size[0] = vp_size[1] = Math.min(vp_size[0], vp_size[1]); 
  //vp_size = [256, 256]
  canvas.width = vp_size[0];
  canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

var ShProg = {
Create: function (shaderList) {
  var shaderObjs = [];
  for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++i_sh) {
      var shderObj = this.Compile(shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage);
      if (shderObj) shaderObjs.push(shderObj);
  }
  var prog = {}
  prog.progObj = this.Link(shaderObjs)
  if (prog.progObj) {
      prog.attrInx = {};
      var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
      for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++i_n) {
          var name = gl.getActiveAttrib(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
          prog.attrInx[name] = gl.getAttribLocation(prog.progObj, name);
      }
      prog.uniLoc = {};
      var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS);
      for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++i_n) {
          var name = gl.getActiveUniform(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
          prog.uniLoc[name] = gl.getUniformLocation(prog.progObj, name);
      }
  }
  return prog;
},
AttrI: function (prog, name) { return prog.attrInx[name]; },
UniformL: function (prog, name) { return prog.uniLoc[name]; },
Use: function (prog) { gl.useProgram(prog.progObj); },
SetI1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1i(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1f(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF2: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform2fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF3: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF4: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetM33: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
SetM44: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
Compile: function (source, shaderStage) {
  var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
  if (shaderScript)
      source = shaderScript.text;
  var shaderObj = gl.createShader(shaderStage);
  gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
  gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
  var status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
  return status ? shaderObj : null;
},
Link: function (shaderObjs) {
  var prog = gl.createProgram();
  for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++i_sh)
      gl.attachShader(prog, shaderObjs[i_sh]);
  gl.linkProgram(prog);
  status = gl.getProgramParameter(prog, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(prog));
  return status ? prog : null;
} };

var VertexBuffer = {
Create: function(attribs, indices, type) {
  var buffer = { buf: [], attr: [], inx: gl.createBuffer(), inxLen: indices.length, primitive_type: type ? type : gl.TRIANGLES };
  for (var i=0; i<attribs.length; ++i) {
      buffer.buf.push(gl.createBuffer());
      buffer.attr.push({ size : attribs[i].attrSize, loc : attribs[i].attrLoc, no_of: attribs[i].data.length/attribs[i].attrSize });
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i]);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attribs[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  }
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  if ( buffer.inxLen > 0 ) {
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  }
  return buffer;
},
Draw: function(bufObj) {
  for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i) {
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i]);
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc);
  }
  if ( bufObj.inxLen > 0 ) {
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx);
      gl.drawElements(bufObj.primitive_type, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
      gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
  }
  else
      gl.drawArrays(bufObj.primitive_type, 0, bufObj.attr[0].no_of );
  for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i)
      gl.disableVertexAttribArray(bufObj.attr[i].loc);
  gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
} };

initScene();

})();
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;
varying vec2 vpos;

void main()
{
    vpos = inPos.xy; 
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>
  
<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision mediump float;
  
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
varying vec2 vpos;

float circle (const vec2 st, float r) {
    return sin(100.0 * length(st));
}

void main() {
    vec2 st     = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    st.x -= 0.5;
    st.y = 1.0 - st.y;
    vec2 offs_x = vec2(1.0 / u_resolution.x, 0.0);
    
    float dist   = circle(st, 0.5);
    float dist_n = circle(st + offs_x, 0.5);
    float dist_p = circle(st - offs_x, 0.5);

    float df1 = dFdx(dist) * 100.0;

    int fc_x = int(gl_FragCoord.x) / 2;
    float df2 = ((fc_x*2 == int(gl_FragCoord.x)) ? dist_n - dist : dist - dist_p) * 100.0;

    vec3 color = mix(vec3(df1), vec3(df2), step(0.0,st.x));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
</script>

<canvas id="canvas" style="border: none"></canvas>
```

Comment: May I ask where could I find more documentation about this detail of the dFdx-calculation, thanks again :)

Comment: @Addict I added some resources to the answer.